# Sistema de reconhecimento facial em php

Tags: php

Gostaria de fazer um sistema  no qual eu salvasse algumas fotos no banco de dados e a partir da webcam eu tirasse uma foto na hora e comparasse com as que tem no banco, já procurei bastante na internet porem só acho reconhecendo o rosto da pessoa, mas não dessa forma.

Comment: não é ideal fazer isso no php..

Comment: +1 não é recomendado o uso do PHP para isso. Aqui tem uma lista de API's: http://blog.mashape.com/list-of-10-face-detection-recognition-apis/

Comment: Tem esse em jquery: http://facedetection.jaysalvat.com/ github: https://github.com/jaysalvat/jquery.facedetection

Comment: Então @DanielOmine realmente vi a galera falando isso que seria melhor fazer em outra linguagem e depois fazer uma forma de ponte no php vou procurar em outras linguagens tambem.

Comment: @juniorb2ss olhei o site que você mandou porem aparentemente as API são todas pagas ou tem que colocar cartão para usar nem que seja por um tempo e eu não tenho cartão, ate consegui entrar no site de algumas e tinha umas que era exatamente o que eu queria mas..  Se tiver mais informações de como usar o site eu agradeço, talvez eu que não tenha entendido como ele funciona.

Comment: @IvanFerrer isso e o que eu mais acho na internet porem não é isso que eu to querendo, seria mais comparar uma imagem com outra, ai ele apenas localiza os rostos na imagem mas muito obrigado.

Comment: APIs de face detection é realmente pago. Encontrar uma open source é pouco complicado e desconheço a existência de alguma.

Comment: Os algoritmos de reconhecimento facial são muito complexos e há investimentos pesados nos que estão bem desenvolvidos.. Naturalmente não encontrará nada gratuito na web que seja razoável. No máximo encontrará serviços que fornecem alguma API paga. Trabalhei com isso em 2007, mas na ocasião fiz script com PHP e PHP-GD que reconhecia movimentos. Foi para câmeras de segurança. Até que funcionava bem, mas longe de ser o ideal em performance. Foi mais em conta, financeiramente, comprar um software já homologado e recomendado comercialmente.

Comment: @juniorb2ss E o problema que eu precisava uma open source, porque o que eu to fazendo é apenas um trabalho academico, vou continuar pesquisando mas se for muito dificil de encontrar algo vou pensar em outra coisa no lugar do reconhecimento facial.

Comment: @DanielOmine realmente, eu mesmo não faço minina ideia de como fazer um programa desses até porque ainda estou aprendendo, e em questão de comprar nem valeria a pena porque é apenas um trabalho academico, e não é TCC então.. Vou continuar pesquisando aqui, mas vou acabar tendo que pensar em outra forma de autenticar.

Comment: Nesse caso, apenas tome cuidado para que o seu trabalho não seja  copiado por terceiros. Normalmente em escolas e universidades, os mentores ou outros colegas se aproveitam da ingenuidade de alguem que consegue criar algo bacana e usa aquilo para fins comerciais. Se vc conseguir criar algo legal, faça registro de patente antes de apresentar. Não caia muito nessa conversa de open source porque sempre tem aproveitador sugando trabalho alheio.

Comment: @DanielOmine Ok vlw pelo aviso.

Comment: Sei que é antigo, mas uma pena ainda encontrar mensagens como essa: "não é recomendado ser feito em PHP". Por que não? ninguem explica, ninguem fala nada, só opiniões. Saibam que até em C# esse tipo de processamento é feito através de apis externas, e é perfeitamente possível o bind com PHP. Se alguém ainda tiver interesse como eu estou tendo agora depois de 3 anos da pergunta, deem uma procurada em opencv. É possível compilar a extensão para o PHP, ou até usar via linha de comando https://github.com/php-opencv/php-opencv-examples

Answer (score 1):

Como já adiantaram nos comentários, o PHP não é a linguagem ideal para fazer o reconhecimento facial propriamente dito.

No entanto, como você vai desenvolver um serviço web, é interessante pensar no PHP como a aplicação web que receberá as fotos, a partir do recebimento das mesmas, você conecta com um serviço ou com uma outra linguagem que fará o reconhecimento propriamente dito.

A própria tarefa de reconhecimento de rostos a partir de imagens não é trivial – você precisa de um banco de dados de imagens, desenvolver uma rede neural, treiná-la para aí então, se tudo der certo, reunir um conjunto de atributos comuns a cada conjunto de fotos da mesma pessoa.

Óbvio que isso também depende muito dos seus requisitos: se você precisa encontrar imagens *idênticas* às existentes atualmente (o que eu acho difícil, já que elas virão de fotos tiradas por webcams) ou com um certo grau de similaridade.

Comment: Como eu disse ali no comentario acima realmente vi algumas pessoas falando isso, que seria melhor fazer uma especie de ponte entre o php e outra linguagem, vou começar a pesquisar em outras linguagens tambem e depois vejo uma forma de fazer essa ponte, em questão de analizar a imagem realmente teria que ser por grau de similaridade. Se achar algum projeto mesmo que em outra linguagem que faz realmente isso eu agradeço, mas claro enquanto isso vou pesquisando tambem. Vi muita galera usando uma biblioteca chamada de OpenCV  não sei exatamente em que ela facilita.